# Are [video lectures] useful?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-blacklist

Let's [burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/burninate-request/info) tag [video-lectures](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-lectures).

As of now, there are 5 questions in this tag. All appear to be off-topic [education advice](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980) / [off-site resource](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487) requests. None looks worth keeping.

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274932/modernizing-my-net-knowledge
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101959/where-can-i-find-windows-via-c-c-video-training
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/85698/trying-to-find-video-of-a-talk-on-the-impact-of-memory-access-latency
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70944/lecture-like-cs-videos
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/67773/is-there-any-online-video-giving-a-useful-insight-on-programming-in-certain-lang

Comment: for the sake of completeness, currently there are [no locked questions in this tag](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bvideo-lectures%5D+locked%3Ayes)

Comment: [And Then There Were None](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_Then_There_Were_None#mediaviewer/File:And_Then_There_Were_None_US_First_Edition_Cover_1940.jpg)

Comment: that was fast - thanks @YannisRizos! [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: The tag isn't blacklisted, and I don't think anyone from SE will bother blacklisting a tag that had less than a dozen questions in its prime. However, now that it doesn't have any questions, it will be harder for newer users to use it. So... [status-good-enough]?

Comment: @YannisRizos agree, plain [burnination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/burninate-request/info) seems to be good enough: "stands for simple deletion of a tag"